# Apache Permission denied for /srv/www: unable to check .htaccess file but not for /var/www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, srv

I've hit a problem on Centos 6.5:

[Mon Dec 28 12:10:52 2012] [a] [client 127.0.0.1] (13) Permission denied: /srv/www/website/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Basically, I was building a brand new server and trying to migrate all of my websites over into /srv/www folder instead of /var/www as it appears to be the future standard (there is a whole discussion about it so just google).

What I did:

1) added a new group (groupadd developers)

2) added users a (gid 501), root, apache, nobody to the above group
   (usermod -G develoeprs a && usermod -G develoeprs apache && usermod -G develoeprs root && usermod -G develoeprs nobody)

3) copied all folders & files into /srv/www

4) changed ownership of entire /srv/www to apache:developers (chown -R apache:developers /srv/www)

5) changed mode so /srv/www is group readable/writable/searchable (chmod -R 2775 /srv/www)

6) added 'umask 002' to the end of /etc/sysconfig/httpd so it runs in group writable mode

7) added virtual host(s) and to /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf (service httpd configtest throws OK)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443

SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.ext
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/test
    ServerName test.domain.com
    ServerAlias test.domain
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/certs/domain.com/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/certs/domain.com/server.key
    <Directory /srv/www/test>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

8) restarted the server
9) started httpd manually because it asks for SSL certificate password otherwise autostart fails (need to look into how to start it automatically after rebooting)

I am still getting the same above error message.

Then, I tried changing the home folder in /etc/passwd for apache user to /srv/www (server restart) but still no joy i.e. Permission denied. I even renamed the old /var/www folder and created a symlink in /var/www to /srv/www. Another attempt was to chown back to root:root, apache:apache and :developers group for both.

/srv/www/  [NOT WORKING]

drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root (cgi-bin, error, html,icons)

drwxrwsr-x. 5 apache developers (all other website folders)

-rwxrwsr-x. 1 apache developers (all files)

/srv/

drwxrwsr-x. 4 apache developers www

/var/www [WORKING]

drwxr-xr-x. 2 root   root (cgi-bin, error, html,icons)

drwxrwxr-x. 3 apache developers (all other website folders)

-rwxrwxr-x. 1 apache developers (all website files)

Then, as soon as I copy my one of my website's folder into /var/www and point paths in /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf it starts to work fine!

DOES ANYONE KNOW WHY IT'S NOT WORKING IN /SRV/WWW folder??

Comment: When I set apache log level to debug then only get this when accessing virtual hosts: X.X.X.X - - [20/Jan/2014:21:30:40 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got to the bottom of the problem. It's caused by SELinux policies overriding basic traditional discretionary access control (DAC) methods such as file permissions or access control lists (ACLs) normally used to control the file access of users!

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted

$ setenforce
usage:  setenforce [ Enforcing | Permissive | 1 | 0 ]

$ setenforce Permissive

$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

More info on SELinux at [Centos](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux). As soon as I switched to Permissive mode my /srv/ started working.

If you know what and why you are doing this then you can permanently disable SELinux in /etc/selinux/config by changing the following line:

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

to

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Restart your server and you should have it disabled permanently.

> Note: When switching from Disabled to either Permissive or Enforcing
>   mode, it is highly recommended that the system be rebooted and the
>   filesystem relabeled.

Comment: You saved my life today. Is there anything I can do to repay you?
@webcoder

Comment: This is very BAD advice in general. SELinux is NOT something you just want to disable _especially_ on a web server!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the user "apache" can cross the folder "/src" ?
What's the owner and the permission of the folder "/src" ?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root  4096 Jan 20 11:55 srv


drwxr-xr-x.  19 root root  4096 Jan 20 10:39 var
Same permissions for both although websites only work in /var.

Comment: Can you test this two commands :  
`chown -R apache:developers /srv/www`  
`chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX /srv/www`

Comment: Forbidden, You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
I'm clueless... permissions seem to be not affecting this at all. I've checked httpd.conf as well and there is nothing specific that would use /var/ folder the only one from which apache can serve websites. This is very odd.

Comment: Also, can read, write and search/execute in /srv/www using any user account from developers group which indicates that permissions are correct.