# web server permission on RHEL7

Tags: php, apache, rhel, rhel7

Premise: I have sufficient knowledge on how to install and deploy web application on Ubuntu based on LAMP stack and tomcat. Now I'm trying to use RedHat7 and I have some issue.

I have a web application under /var/www/html/ directory on RHEL7 server. I'm able to reach index page in which there is a login form. This login calls a php page that performs a db call. In this case I have an error in my /var/log/httpd/app1_error.log file:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 8 attempt to write a readonly database in
>   /var/www/html/[omiss]loginPortal.php:82\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/html/[omiss]/loginPortal.php(82):
>   PDO->exec('DELETE FROM use...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/html/[omiss]/loginPortal.php on
>   line 82, referer:

seems that php page doesn't have sufficient permission on database. Database is a sqllite3 db. I Know that in REHL7 i don't have www-data user an group but instead I use apache user and group, so my web directory has apache group and I give 777 permission (I know it is not secure, I'm just tryng to figure out the problem). Despite 777 permission I still have the same problem.  Anyone has hints?

If it helps this is my output for ls -lZ command

> drwxrwxrwx. apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 myApp

so I think httpd_sys_content_t is the correct SELinux context

Comment: Have you tried setting context to "public_content_rw_t" using semanage? [CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-bf0af694056e0c6bbe299e80817630346d5401f6) applicable to RHEL.

Comment: i quote: " public_content_rw_t context i  has directories that need to be shared by NFS, Samba and Apache. This context seems to allow this to happen. It's probably also a security hole so beware on security conscious systems" i'm not really sure, I'm trying to understand if it has no side effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this solution that worked for me: basically

```
setenforce Permissive
```

Reference: [Apache permission on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233552/apache-permission-denied-for-srv-www-unable-to-check-htaccess-file-but-not-fo?rq=1)

thanks everybody